# Place order error Message queue topic "inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus" is not configured. in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, salable, reservations

when i click place order button i get this message

> Message queue topic "inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus" is
> not configured.

and order has place in backend but i still get this message always[image]

Comment: Learn This. May be help for you.https://github.com/magento/inventory/pull/3170

Comment: How did you solve this one @Anonymous Dev

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking where that is used so don't know the bottom of that but atleast there might be need to add consumer for that:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/rabbitmq-overview.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html

list of consumers to add:
bin/magento queue:consumers:list

inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

how did you fixed that problem? facing same thing : Message queue topic "inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus" is not configured after place order. Magento 2.3